# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, command-line, podfile

I got an error when I tried to add flutter to an existing iOS app it worked fine on the android side, in IOS I got this error message :

```
/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fixit- dffmmspbqmueppghdvveloietubr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Fixit.build/Debug- iphoneos/Fixit.build/Script-04B0EA9A232E6ABD008A0448.sh: line 3: /packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: No such file or directory

/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fixit- dffmmspbqmueppghdvveloietubr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Fixit.build/Debug- iphoneos/Fixit.build/Script-04B0EA9A232E6ABD008A0448.sh: line 4: /packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh: No such file or directory

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

inside my pod file i added this inside target application:

```
flutter_application_path = '⁨Users⁩/mac⁩/FixitApps⁩/customerApp⁩/fixit_flutter_customer_app/'
eval(File.read(File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb')), binding)
```

I followed this tutorial: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you create a script file in the build phase for building dart code remove it and add this to your podfile :

```
flutter_application_path = '⁨Users⁩/mac⁩/FixitApps⁩/customerApp⁩/fixit_flutter_customer_app/'
eval(File.read(File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb')), binding)

install_all_flutter_pods(flutter_application_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I have deleted some files from assets but forget to remove from pubspes.yaml.

Error solved after

1. remove deleted files from pubspes.yaml
2. click on `pub get`.
3. run on device

Answer (score 0):

I am using a cloud virtual computer to build my iOS apps, in that case when I'm building the app, the machine got disconnected after I connect it again this above error popped up. But after I turn off the machine and restarted it, this error did not pop up.