# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code Flutter IOS

Tags: flutter

I have this error when try archive

mckenneth@MacBook-Air-de-Mckenneth proyectotestflutter % flutter build ios --release
Running "flutter pub get" in proyectotestflutter...                 0.4s

Building pe.com.frsystem.proyectotestflutter for device (ios-release)...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team
in Xcode project: MR26KAPBN4
Running Xcode build...

Xcode build done.                                           35.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
```

Encountered error while building for device.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyFpO.png)

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49495

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23465

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944714/command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code-flutter
please follow these links.
Thanks